# matching overlapping regex perl

Tags: regex, overlapping

I'm trying to write a script that will match regex that are overlapping.  I've gotten some pointers from previous questions but can't seem to overcome my problem.  I'm trying to find any regex starting with 'aaa' and then containing any multiple of 3 characters, and ending with 'ccc'. my script is this:

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   $string = aaatttcccxaaattcccxaaattttttcccxaaattttttccc;
   while ($string =~ /aaa(...)+?ccc/ig) {
       my $string_name = $&;
       my $len_string = length $&;
       my $position = pos $string;
       my $start_position = ($position - $len_string) + 1;
       my $end_position = pos $string;
       print "String \'$string_name\' of length $len_string was found at position $start_position through $end_position.\n\n";
       print "\n";
    }
```

My output is below:

```
      String 'aaatttccc' of length 9 was found at position 1 through 9.

      String 'aaattcccxaaattttttccc' of length 21 was found at position 11 through 31.

      String 'aaattttttccc' of length 12 was found at position 33 through 44.
```

It fails to find the string 'aaattttttccc' that is within the second output (from position 19-31), and should be the third output.

How do I make it look for overlapping regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your regex when matches `aaattcccxaaattttttccc`, regex match position is already at the end of `aaattcccxaaattttttccc` and it cannot go back to match `aaattttttccc` again.

You can use lookhead regex:

```
(aaa)(?=((?:...)+?ccc))
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP3hO6/1)

And grab captured group #1 and captured group #2 for every match.

---

#### Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $str = 'aaatttcccxaaattcccxaaattttttcccxaaattttttccc';

while ( $str =~ /(aaa)(?=((?:...)+?ccc))/g ) {
   print "$1$2\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I see that this works in the demo, but this only captures 'aaa' in my script now.  I've tried more combinations but for some reason just can't get this to work.